# jQuery and CSS not working in sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2013

my web part `jQuery` and `CSS` code does not work after I deploy to sharepoint 2013 server.

I like to ask is it because of the `"runat=server"`? I am using it because i need to identify the html element and bind with a class constant value at the backend code.

Can anyone advise me how should i deploy the `jQuery` and `CSS`? 
Here is My Codes

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.icon').mouseover(function () {
        $(".menuLink").stop(true, false).fadeIn(280);
        $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "300px",
            opacity: "1",
            "padding-left": "10px"
        });
    });
    $('.divTableBody').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "0px",
            opacity: "0",
            "padding-left": "0px"
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.divTable {
    display: table;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #0082CA;
}

.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.menuLink, .icon {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.menuLink {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.menuLink a {
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.divTableRow:hover {
    background-color: #005C8F;
}

.icon {
    width: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.icon img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.userProfile {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Make the badge float in the top right corner of the button */
#badge {
    background-color: #fa3e3e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute; /* Position the badge within the relatively positioned button */
    top: 20px;
    right: 8px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="menuLink">
                <a id="txtLink1" runat="server"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <img id="imgLink1" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot find the elements by the ID's **you specified on server side** (by implementing `runat="server"`). The value of the ID is **changed for clientside** with a prefix containing information about parent elements (inspect in the browser).

You can use `ClientIDMode="static"` to prevent this and preserve the ID value

apply this property to all applicable html.

```
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="menuLink">
                <a id="txtLink1"  ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <img id="imgLink1"  ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[read more on MSDN here...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: do you mean all html tag? for example, my div tag need "ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"?